# How to get the Numpy array of file stream of any image

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to use the imageai python library, and more particularly this function:

```
detector.detectObjectsFromImage()
```

The doc says it should be used with a Numpy array of file stream of any image.

https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detection/index.html

When I pass it a Numpy array, like this:

```
detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=anumpyarray,input_type = "array")
```

I get the error:

> detections =
>   detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=anumpyarray,input_type =
>   "array") File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageai/Detection/**init**.py",
>   line 517, in detectObjectsFromImage raise ValueError("Ensure you
>   specified correct input image, input type, output type and/or output
>   image path ") ValueError: Ensure you specified correct input image,
>   input type, output type and/or output image path

Is it because a Numpy array and a Numpy array of a stream of an image are different things?

Comment: One thing to note is, if you re-read the documentation for that function, you don't _have_ to pass it a Numpy array, it's just possible. You can also just pass it the path of an image.

Comment: Sure, but I'm analyzing a video through an iterator which gives me numpy file. I would be too costly to save each image just to pass it to the function. That's why I want to pass it directly as a numpy array

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but for anyone who needs help:

Try to set 2 additional params:

```py
minimum_percentage_probability=0, output_type='array'
```

For more info, go into `imageai\Detection\__init__.py -> detectObjectsFromImage`